# How to use Lesser divs with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

using `bootstrap 3.3.7` 
The structure wanted is found in the link below. The problem is to solve this kind of a grid system by using lesser `divs` as much as possible.
First, we have a div with a class `col` which takes the whole block. Next, we have another grid below it which also takes the whole block on large screens. Whereas on mobile phone the first grid will take the left part and the other one the right.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="border:1px solid;">
      <span> here goes the image  on the top
                    - on small device it should be to the left 
                    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-7 col-xs-8" style="border:1px solid;">
      <span> here goes the content on the bottom that include some other grids
                    - on small device it should be to the right of the image above
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="border:1px solid;">
      <span>
        *Second div*
        here goes the image  on the top
                    - on small device it should be to the left 
                    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-7 col-xs-8" style="border:1px solid;">
      <span> here goes the content on the bottom that include some other grids
                    - on small device it should be to the right of the image above
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add an image that illustrates what you want to achieve?

Comment: you should wrap all `col-`'s in `.row`'s with Bootstrap

Comment: What do you mean by 'using lesser divs as much as possible'?

Comment: What is meant by 'lesser divs' is that I don't want to have lots of nested divs

Comment: is it what you want?: http://www.codeply.com/go/AuqWTubRUg  or space shoulb be between columns on small viewport?

Answer (score 0):

Use this codes and change your `col-xs-[]` `col-md-[]` and enjoy..

```css
.border{
border:1px solid red;
}
.height{
min-height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 border height">
    <div>
      here goes the content on the bottom that include some other grids - on small device it should be to the right of the image above

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 border height">
    <div>
      here goes the content on the bottom that include some other grids - on small device it should be to the right of the image above

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 border height">
    <div>
      here goes the content on the bottom that include some other grids - on small device it should be to the right of the image above

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 border height">
    <div>
      here goes the content on the bottom that include some other grids - on small device it should be to the right of the image above

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```